# Spring MVC 3 programatic loading of messages properties based on user preference language

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I have basic Spring MVC 3 setup for i18n where I can show labels on page based on user passed language in the request. For example: url?lang=fr, url?lang=de etc...

But actual requirement is I have to maintain 2 properties files for each locale, for example for French, I will have messages_fr_fr.properties and messages_fr_en.properties. Similarly for germany locale, I will have messages_de_de.properties and messages_de_en.properties.

That means when french user logs in, page will show french labels, but he can switch to english from a drop down if he wants. This requires programatic loading messages properties, how do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [reference](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-localeresolver), I believe using `LocaleChangeInterceptor` helps you change the language at runtime and load the messages likewise. A more detailed example is described [here](http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-internationalization-example/).